# Rotas do Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Estou usando o Codeigniter e só a rota

`$route['default_controller'] = 'welcome';`

está funcionando, quando eu faço uma exemplo:

`$route['teste'] = "welcome";`

ele me dá a seguinte mensagem 
**Cannot GET /codeigniter/index.php/teste** .
Alguém saberia me informar o que pode ser ? Essa pasta que contem o codeigniter está dentro de outra aplicação

Answer (score 1):

As rotas no codeigniter são para dar nome a caminhos, por exemplo no seu caso a rota padrão ao se abrir a index da pagina é:

`$route['default_controller'] = 'welcome';`

Onde default_controller significa que é o nome para o novo caminho e welcome e o controller deste caminho, no controller que se carrega as view que no caso é a pagina visual.

Também pode ser um erro por você fazer duas chamadas ao um controller em rotas diferentes, neste caso não sei se é possível ou não utilizar, provavelmente seja possível.

no seu caso ele esta informando que não conseguiu encontrar a controller welcome. Tente mudar de `"welcome"`para `'welcome'` e ver se a controller welcome ainda existe dentro da pasta application/controller.

para mais duvidas talvez este link te ajude:

http://codeigniterbrasil.com/configuracoes/configuracao-rotas-routes-codeigniter/

Porem se você não sabe como se trabalha com MVC e codeigniter terá algum trabalho para conseguir fazer o que se deseja.

Porem este site tem grande conteúdo sobre codeigniter e pessoas que já trabalham a um bom tempo com este, eu prefiro laravel principalmente para se trabalhar com rotas, mas já utilizei codeigniter em dois trabalhos anteriores.

Att.
Thiago Prado

Comment: O problema é só que ele não está localizando as rotas, o conceito e tudo mais , eu entendo e consigo fazer de outras formas, acredito eu que esteja dando algum erro , porque estou usando o yeoman com php-cgi junto para conseguir executar. Também uso o Laravel, mas nesse caso, tenho que usar o Codeigniter.

Comment: Sem adicionar a nova rota ainda existe o problema? Ou só começou quando se criou esta nova rota?

Comment: Aproveitando qual foi a forma que você fez a chamada a teste?
Você fez: `http://meusite/teste` ou `http://meusite/index.php/teste`?

Comment: Tentei criar um vhost aqui com uma aplicação codeigniter zerada e foi tudo certo.

`$route['default_controller'] = "welcome";`
`$route['404_override'] = '';`
`$route['teste'] = "welcome";`

acessei por `http://codeigniter.app/index.php/teste` e o acesso se sucedeu normalmente sem erros, provavelmente alguma modificação nos configs do codeigniter causaram o crash, ou esta faltando alguma informação neste arquivo de rotas.

Answer (score 0):

Você já declarou sua rota padrão.

```
 $route['default_controller'] = 'welcome';
```

Caso queira chamar o controler `teste` deve trocar o controle padrão para 
`$route['default_controller'] = 'teste';`